# counting the number of nodes is not working

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<food>
    <cuisine type="Chinese">
        <restaurant name = "Panda Express">
            <location id= "0"></location>
            <phone id = "1"></phone>
            <city id="2"></phone>
        </restaurant>
        <restaurant name = "Mr. Chau's">

        </restaurant>
    </cuisine>
    <cuisine type="Indian">
        <restaurant name = "Shan">

        </restaurant>
    </cuisine>
</food>
```

and I am trying to count the number of cuisine nodes this is the code I have, I know its mostly right but when I try to print out the length of the nodelist it says it's 0

```
//starts talking to the xml document
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","data.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlData = xmlhttp.responseXML;


        //fills the first comboBox
        var sel = document.getElementById('CuisineList');
        cuisineList = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('cuisine');
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = cuisineList.length;
```

Comment: Strongly recommend **not** doing synchronous ajax requests (that `false` as the third argument to `open` makes it synchronous); use an *asynchronous* request and `onreadystatechangehandler` callback instead. Synchronous ajax requests make for a poor user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible answers:

A) The XML has an error, you have `</phone>` where you need `</city>`. So you'll need to fix that. :-) (But I'm guessing that's just in the question, not in your real data, because if it were in your real data you wouldn't be getting `0`, I wouldn't think; you'd be getting an error.)

B) Check your response headers, it may be that your server isn't returning the XML with the correct MIME type. If not:

1. The best answer is to correct the server configuration so that it serves XML files correctly.
2. If for whatever reason you can't do that, you can use `overrideMimeType` to force the `XMLHttpRequest` to treat the response as XML:

   ```
   xmlhttp.open("GET","data.xml", false);
   xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml"); // <=== The new bit
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlData = xmlhttp.responseXML;
   ```

If you fix those, it works: [Live working copy](http://jsbin.com/inobev) | [source](http://jsbin.com/inobev/edit)